Error in Converting Latitude and Longitude Coordinates to City Names in Large Datasets
I want to convert latitude and longitude to city with a large dataset.
The code I use is as follows:
import numpy as np
import geopy
import time

def get_city_with_retry(df, geolocator, lat_field, lon_field, retries=3, delay=1):
    for _ in range(retries):
        try:
            location = geolocator.reverse((df[lat_field], df[lon_field]), exactly_one=True)
            return location.raw['address'].get('city', location.raw['address'].get('town', 'Unknown'))
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error occurred for coordinates ({df[lat_field]}, {df[lon_field]}): {e}")
            time.sleep(delay)
    return 'Unknown'

# Initialize geolocator
geolocator = geopy.Nominatim(user_agent='my-geocoding-app/1.0')

# Apply the function with retry logic
transactions_data['City'] = transactions_data.apply(lambda row: get_city_with_retry(row, geolocator, 'Latitude', 'Longitude'), axis=1)

# Display the result
print(transactions_data)

but there are errors, such as:

WARNING:urllib3.connectionpool:Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7e790e6b7fd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused')': /reverse?lat=-7.964164&lon=112.623673&format=json&addressdetails=1
WARNING:urllib3.connectionpool:Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7e790e6b6320>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused')': /reverse?lat=-7.964164&lon=112.623673&format=json&addressdetails=1
Error occurred for coordinates (-7.964164, 112.623673): HTTPSConnectionPool(host='nominatim.openstreetmap.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /reverse?lat=-7.964164&lon=112.623673&format=json&addressdetails=1 (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7e790e6b5cc0>, 'Connection to nominatim.openstreetmap.org timed out. (connect timeout=1)'))

what is another solution for the code?

From the error you provided, it looks like a timeout issue. Try setting the timeout parameter when initializing the geolocator like this-
geolocator = geopy.Nominatim(user_agent='my-geocoding-app/1.0', timeout=10)


I've tried it and it still gives the error:
WARNING:urllib3.connectionpool:Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7e790e89e140>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused')': /reverse?lat=-7.974781&lon=112.633863&format=json&addressdetails=1
